# Hide component link in Dreamweaver Template

Tags: templates, dreamweaver, tridion

Dreamweaver template is using the following code to generate the component link. Can this be set up in a way to hide the actual text if the component link has not got a landing page?

```
  <a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">@@Component.Fields.Title@@</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the attribute:
 `tridion:textonfail="False"` to hide text if the link cannot be resolved (no landing page). Default value is **True**

Comment: Here is a link to additional documentation on how to render dynamic links (login required): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-359728360